# T5577 125 khz RFID cards do not work with EM4100 reader

Tags: rfid

I have copied an EM4100 readonly tag to T5577 rewritable tag, and as far as I've heard, T5577 should be able to fully emulate EM4100 when read. But, for some reason, the reader I'm testing my copied tag on does not accept it, while data bytes are the same and the tool I use on check identified the tag as EM4100. Does T5577 still somehow identifies itself as such, or can the target reader somehow tell them apart?